# Why White Screen?

Tags: laptop, hp-laptop, white-screen

This is the first time I am facing this issue.

I used my laptop computer today and it worked fine. Then I shut down my laptop and a few moments later I turned it on again **and it didn't boot up rather, it was showing a white screen containing some black and colored RGB line.** Then I pressed the power button and switched off the laptop **and start again. It worked.** But the white screen is showing frequently.

My Laptop' Model is:
HP-1000 Notebook PC series-1311TU currently running Windows 8.1
and it does not have any dedicated graphics card.

I am afraid if something serious happened. **Is there any solution?**

Answer (score 0):

By your description, it happens sometimes and not others and so likely here it is a hardware issue.

A likely possibility is the ribbon connecting motherboard to screen. This flexes and may have developed a break.

Best advice here:  Take the machine to a local Repair Shop and have it serviced.

Contact the shop to see what your options are.

Taking the laptop apart is a bit tricky:  screwdriver and clip release tool to remove covers to get at screws. Probably something you should leave to a shop.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MzPJ5_bVHw

Comment: Thanks. But due to covid-19 lockdown I cannot go to the repair shop and I need to use my laptop badly. I need some advise that will help m solve the issue alone.

Comment: Open the laptop and try a couple of times to start it. Once started, leave it open and running and then contact a repair shop to see what your options are.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a hardware error. To check for errors yourself before taking the
computer to a repair-shop, you could do the following:

- Run `chkdsk` to check for disk corruption
- Check the SMART data of the disk (for example using
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
- Run
  [SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html):

  ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
    sfc /scannow
  ```
- If nothing is found, the repair-shop is the best next stop.